# MySQL vs PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, postgresql

I am torn between PostgreSQL and MySQL. I am forced to install the chosen one on Windows. I especially need ASP.NET Membership and NHibernate as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK either one of them should work fine if your requirements are fairly low. If you want to use more advanced db stuff, PostgreSQL is probably the better choice, but for simple stuff it doesn't really matter.

My recommendation is to pick the one you have experience administering, or that is used elsewhere in the organization.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend PostgreSQL too. It´s more robust and offers a lot more (triggers, custom types, etc) than MySQL. Last time I looked in MySQL (4.x) there´s nothing of this.

Here at work we choose PostgreSQL for our intranet software 4 years ago and we are very satisfied.

Comment: MySQL 5 has grown quite a bit since then, you might want to check it out.  PostgreSQL still has more features and capabilities but it's getting there.

Comment: MySQL is more robust than mySQL? :)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently gotten MySQL with NHibernate and Asp.Net Membership working without too much hassle.  Check out this related post:  [AccountController using MySQL in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185187/accountcontroller-using-mysql-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is clearly the technical more advanced database managment system, while MySQL is probably a bit simpler to run, is more widely used and in consequence offers more support sources on the internet.

(I am a PostgreSQL user.)